Voltage measured by a Volt meter on a coil
This question is asked on the 2002 Canadian Association of Physicists Prize Exam:

By all logic, the voltage across an inductor in a circuit should be the same as the induced EMF. Or, if there is also resistance in the inductor, the induced EMF plus the current times the resistance should be the measured voltage drop.
The given answer is d. I cannot conceive how that might be the case. Is the answer given wrong?

You should read Ján Lalinský’s answer in this post  How can we derive the polarity of the induced voltage in an inductor?.

"EMF" is not a scientifically useful concept. Many different meanings are attributed to it by different authors, and for that reason none of them are useful. The question is meaningless.
Sydney Ross (1991), "Supplementary Note to The story of the Volta potential". Nineteenth-century attitudes: men of science. Springer. p. 83:
"We have refrained from using the term 'electromotive force' or 'e.m.f.' for short; for there is no consistency between different authors in the meaning of the term. … To some authors it is synonymous with 'voltage.' To others it means the open-circuit voltage of a battery. To a third group of authors it means the open-circuit voltage of any two-terminal device. This use is met most often in connection with Thevenin's theorem in circuit theory. To a fourth group it means the work accounted for by agencies other than differences of the (not measurable) Galvani potentials. Such authors equate the current– resistance product of a circuit branch to the sum of voltage plus e.m.f. A fifth group extends this use to field theory. The authors of this group equate the product of current density and resistivity to the sum of electric-field strength plus an e.m.f. gradient. A sixth group applies the term to electromagnetic induction. These authors define e.m.f. as the spatial line integral of the electric-field strength taken over a complete loop. To them the term 'counter e.m.f.' means something."

I think that your criticism is too severe. EMF is a term which is used and although it may have a multitude of definition in general, it has a particular meaning for this exam as The CAP High School Exam is based upon an internationally recognized syllabus, the I.B. Physics Higher Core Curriculum, ie one syllabus/specification, equivalent to one definition. However I do agree that even if emf has been defined the question is a very poor one.

@Farcher Do you want to make physics a "soft science"? Do we need seven or more mutually inconsistent "schools of physics" because people start using poorly defined terms? There are well-defined concepts (like voltage, vector potential, or E-field line integral, agreed upon in many textbooks) that should be used here. Which EMF definition do you actually want here to make the suggested answer "d" the right one? (I'm really curious, but I'm not going to chase a "CAP High School syllabus" to find it out. Please enlighten me!)

I agree with you that it is a poor question but where I disagree with you is about the use of the term emf. If you read Ján Lalinský’s answer to a post which I cited above it seems that he has little doubt that the term is useful and meaningfully, Induced emf for the path defined by coils of the inductor is defined as integral of induced electric field over that path.

@Farcher No, too ambiguous! "Induced" by what? By the inductance only or by the resistive impedance as well? And only the self-inductance or also mutual? "Induced" presumably does not mean the complete E-field integral, so that opens a can of worms. (But even if we use the complete E-field integral for this question, and assume that the path should obviously  be through the center of the wire following all the windings, how would you get answer "d" and have the meter measure less than the result of this integral? Please, take away the suspense!)
